# Fetch Data between 2 specific dates automatically in DB2

Tags: date, db2

Here I'm with another unusual requirement.

Ok, so I have BO webi report (db2 database), and the report is supposed to run on 5th of every month and then it should have only data between a certain billing cycle (**26th to 25th of last month**)

So basically if I run the report on **5th of March**, it should have data of billing cycle** 26th Jan - 25th Feb**.

I know I can manually put the dates in the query every month and run the report, but this report is going to be a schedule. So has to run automatically.

Any ideas ? Any date functions that can particularly tells a query to run between those  dates ?

have not tried anything yet, but trying to come up a syntax. no clue :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have whatever date of the same month as `2022-03-05`, then you may get your date intervals as follows.

```
WITH PAR (DT) AS (VALUES '2022-03-05'::DATE)
SELECT 
  DT - (DAY (DT) - 1) - 2 MONTH + 25 AS DATE_FROM
, DT - (DAY (DT) - 1) - 1 MONTH + 24 AS DATE_TO  
FROM PAR;
```

| DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-02-25 |